# Can you get a list of Firefox add-ons programmatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I spent a fair amount of time trying to determine why my view of a site didn't match a clients, after looking at the cache etc. we determined the problem to be with one of the add-ons (Adblock Plus in this particular case). It would have been much simpler if we could have had an easy way to query what add-ons were installed, and ideally active. Is there anyway to generate a list programmatically perhaps with JavaScript?

Comment: I should point out that Adblock is designed to hide itself from userland JavaScript as much as possible!

Comment: What makes you think your site has a right to know what software a user has installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do this with user/page JavaScript.  I imagine it would be a security risk, if you could.

But there is an add-on you can install that will generate a printable, copyable list of installed extensions/Add-ons.

Check out: ["Extension List Dumper"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3746/).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a complete list just by using Javascript, but some Addons allow a check anyway.

> accessing the chrome://-protocol was considered a security risk and
>   therefore has been  [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Updating_web_applications_for_Firefox_3#section_7). Nonetheless you can still accomplish to detect
>   an extension with the image-load trick. Why? Because extension
>   developers may mark their extension as web-accessible setting the
>   property “contentaccessible=yes” inside the chrome.manifest file of
>   the extension. This is e.g. the case for the two famous plugins
>   Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar

source: http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/