# Javascript to list IE add ons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, add-on, bho

I am trying to get list of all add ons installed in **IE** through a script.

I used the below code, but it only lists the `ActiveXObject` and I also need browser helper objects with this?

**Javascript:**

```
var L = navigator.plugins.length;

document.write(
  L.toString() + " Plugin(s)<br>" +
  "Name | Filename | description<br>"
);

for(var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
  document.write(
    navigator.plugins[i].name +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].filename +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].description +
    " | " +
    navigator.plugins[i].version +
    "<br>"
  );
}
```

Comment: looks similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380452/can-you-get-a-list-of-firefox-add-ons-programmtically

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the concepts of add-ons and plugins. Plugins are for processing specific content-types (like PDF reader), add-ons are for extending browser functionality (like AdBlock). `navigator.plugins` gives you the list of the plugins, whereas there's no way of getting the list of the BHO add-ons from the client script.

However it could still be possible to indirectly identify some of them by modifications they make to the content of the page (e.g. altering content or adding new elements like images, links or iframes)