# How to get name and version from an extension (Add-ons)

Tags: javascript

is there a way to get the name and version of an add-ons installed in my Firefox web browser??

especially in javascript??

Thansk's

Comment: What's your web browser ?

Comment: This migt help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380452/can-you-get-a-list-of-firefox-add-ons-programmatically